How to connect 3 tables in supabase using flutter?
I have three tables on Supabase:

users : [Here id is the primary key]




id
name
username
email











2.social_accounts: [Here user_id is foreign key from user table]



id
user_id
icon_name
icon_url











3.contact_req: [Here request_to and request_from is foreign key from users table]



id
request_to
request_from
verification_status











How do I connect these three tables based on ID?
Currently I can connect only two tables:
Future<List<ContactReq>> fetchConnectionRequests(String id) async {
  final myQuery = Supabase.instance.client
      .from('contact_req')
      .select('*, users!inner(name)');

  final response =
      await myQuery.or('request_to.eq.$id,request_from.eq.$id');

  // print(response);
  List<ContactReq> requests = contactReqFromJson(jsonEncode(response));

  return requests;
}

I also want to connect social_account here. How do I do it? What i want is to get social_account details based on their user_id on contact_req.
  final myQuery = Supabase.instance.client
      .from('contact_req')
      .select('*, users!inner(name)');

  final response =
      await myQuery.or('request_to.eq.$id,request_from.eq.$id');

  // print(response);
  List<ContactReq> requests = contactReqFromJson(jsonEncode(response));

  return requests;
}```

this is what I tried but couldn't connect social_account.

